# loading external javascripts with GAE

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, loading, external

I'm having some trouble loading external javascripts using google app engine.
I basically have an index.html file with the following on the header section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jsfunctions.js"></script>
```

and the following in the body section:

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<button  type="button" onclick = DisplayDate() >Display Date</button>
```

In the jsfunctions.js file, I have:

```
function DisplayDate(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Date();
}
```

When I run this, I can see that the page gets the jsfunctions.js:

```
INFO 2012-05-06 00:37:25,864 dev_appserver.py:2884] "GET /jsfunctions.js HTTP/1.1" 404
```

However, nothing happens when I click on the button.

Am I missing something important here?

Comment: Sorry,
 
I screwed up the code formatting, here it is again:

I basically have an index.html file with the following on the header section:
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jsfunctions.js"></script>

and the following in the body section:

    <p id="demo"></p>
    <button  type="button" onclick = DisplayDate() >Display Date</button>

Comment: We'll need to see your `app.yaml` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you declare a `static_files` entry for `jsfunctions.js` (or put it in a subdirectory that you declare with `static_dir`), your handler has to be prepared to serve it.

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Static_Directory_Handlers

Answer (score 0):

The transfer log entry says 404, that means your js file was not loaded. Double check that it is being served when you enter the URL to the file.

Comment: That helps me narrow the problem down, any clue why it would be complaining?  All my files are in the top directory and the name of the javascript is correct and matches.  Is there something else I need to configure for google apps engine to fetch it?

Thank You